# How to implement prototypical inheritance when using object factories?

Tags: javascript

I've learned about the function constructors and function factories,

to implement inheritance when using function constructors, we use the prototype property:

```js
//Object constructor
const Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name; //as an example
}

//instances:
person1 = new Person("omar");
//LOOK HERE
console.log(person1.getName()) //you'll get a result
```

But what about function factories? how can we implement prototypal inheritance when using function factories?

```js
//Object factory
const Person = function(name) {
  return {
    name
  }
}

//----<WRONG CODE>
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name; //as an example
}
//--------- </WRONG CODE>
//instances:
person1 = Person("omar");
//LOOK HERE
console.log(person1.getName()) //you'll get an error!
```

the first code is different from the second code, How can I make the second code have the same result of the first code but with the use of object factories rather than using object constructors?

The difference as you can see is that in the first code I can see that the `person1` can access the `getName` method (`person1.getName()`), while in the second code, `person1` can't access the `getName` method (`person1.getName()`).

Comment: Please turn off your caps lock when typing questions. It reads as yelling in many areas of the internet.

Comment: I'm not angry :)

Comment: sorry i've edited the code, there was a problem

Comment: The question is: the first code is different from the second code, How can I make the second code have the same result of the first code but with the use of object factories rather than using object constructors?

Comment: The difference as you can see is that in the first code I can see that the person1 can access the getName method (person1.getName()), while in the second code, person1 can't access the getName method (person1.getName()).

Comment: @JanStránský, I want person1 to get the getName method from the Person.prototype in the first code and the second code

Comment: I've edited the question again

Comment: The downovotes are not because of the question itself, but because it is not clear enough what you are asking (maybe it is now after many edits, but to prevent downvotes next time, focus on writing a good question without the need of editing). And because of the initial caps-lock. And that it talks about inheritance, but the problem is not about inheritance at all.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `getName` method directly to the constructed object. Do not use `prototype` in the "non-prototype" creation.

```js
const person = function(name){
    return {
        name,
        getName() {
            return this.name
        },
    }
}

person1 = person("omar");
console.log(person1.getName())
```

EDIT

Now when it is clear what you want to achieve, I think it is not possible. In the second approach, `Person` is "normal" function. Iside this normal function, you create a local variable and return it. The function and returned object are independent and because the returned object is local to the function, you cannot access it (before it is returned).

You can still use prototype, e.g. using `Object.create` using a globally defined prototype. You can then extent that prototype, but not directly the `Person` function.

```js
PersonProto = {}

const Person = function(name){
    var ret = Object.create(PersonProto)
    ret.name = name
    return ret
}
PersonProto.getName = function(){ return this.name }

person1 = Person("omar");
console.log(person1.getName())
```

Comment: I know that I can do it this way, but this is not what I meant, I wanted to implement prototypical inheritance with the use of object factories.
if I do it this way it will work of course, but the name of this implementation is no longer called "prototypical inheritance" because the function getName is directly defined inside the object itself.

Comment: Of course it is not called "prototypical inheritance", because it has nothing to do with inheritance

Comment: Yes, and this is the point! I want it to be a  "prototypical inheritance" exactly like the first code (the one with the use of function constructor)

Comment: The first case has nothing to do with inheritance, too

Comment: No? what? I am defining the getName function inside the Person.prototype, (so: Person.prototype.getName), this way Everytime a new instance from the object Person (such as person1) will inherit this method from his parent (which is Person.prototype.getName)

Comment: ok, sorry, I was not switched to javascript and remained in the bubble of classical class inheritance..

Comment: I have edited my answer. This is IMO the closest you can achieve.

Comment: yes friend, after some thinking and investigation I've reached your same solution